# convert os.system to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, subprocess, os.system

I am writing a script to open a new command prompt, and run an executable. I got a working code using `os.system`. Can you help me transform it to `subprocess.Popen`?

```
hello_exe = r'c:\hello.exe'
os.system("start cmd /k {}".format(hello_exe))
```

I cannot run `hello_exe` as a background process because I want the user to see the command prompt and be able to scroll through the logs. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My environment: Windows8 and python 2.7.12

Comment: Use `subprocess.call('cmd.exe /k "{}"'.format(hello_exe), creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. The only purpose of `cmd.exe /k` here is to leave a process attached to the console after hello.exe exits. It's otherwise not required and has nothing to do with allocating the new console. Leave it out if it's ok for the console to close after hello.exe exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I cannot use it directly because hello_exe is an indefinitely running program (only terminates if closed by a user or terminated by my python script). And I don't want subprocess.call() to block my script. I changed .call to .Popen and it did the job I wanted. Thanks alot, your creationflags did the magic that I can't find in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to `subprocess.Popen` is like this:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(r'c:\hello.exe', shell = True)
process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to Popen

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

hello_exe = r'c:\hello.exe'

proc = Popen(hello_exe, stdout=PIPE, shell = True)
proc.communicate()
```

Here are few links which you can refer to understand [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

[Link to understand Popen](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/#popen)

[Another link to understand Popen](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_subprocess_module.php)

[Link to 50+ examples of Popen](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50/subprocess.Popen)

Comment: thank you. creationflags mentioned in first answer really did the trick